# Visual artefact in viewport

Tags: 3d-view, artifacts, settings

Pretty new to blender, but i've tried to find a solution and came up blank (lots of other types of artifacting obscuring search results).

Below is my view of just a default cube. It's very annoying to see what i'm doing when getting more complex objects involved...

How can I clean this up? AA just 'smoothes' the edges of the artefacting :p I'm on Desktop 3600X + 1080Ti, so performance should be there.

Kind regards and thanks in advance!

[image: my-blender-viewport1]

[image: my-blender-viewport2]

Comment: Can you please share your blend file?

Comment: In the N panel > View, try to change the Clip Start and End values

Comment: Looks like some kind of OpenGL error. Try enabling "High Quality Normals" under _Render Properties > Performance_. Also make sure your graphics drivers are up to date.